# Is there any no need of worshipping/ believing God for material benefits? & For liberation, is recommended but optional?

Tags: gods, philosophy

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2952/8696) answer explains the need of worshipping God. The answerer is talking about the impossibility of getting **liberation** without being a devotee. But Gautam Buddha & Mahavir proved the statement wrong. One crosses the cycle of death & birth using teachings of Gautam Buddha where one neither worship any Deity nor believe in any soul. So -

- Does worshipping/believing God for sake of liberation is **optional though recommended only**? Not mandatory?

Also, `As You reap what you sow`, there is no possibility that the God will help you to accomplish material things in your life. In fact, success & failures are result of our **Karmas** only, then

- There is no need of worshipping/believing God for material benefits **at all**? ( Because Karma is taking care about the material possessions. )

Comment: Doing Pujas or going to Piligrimage places come under Good Karma. So, this good karma can also be used to fulfill desires.

Comment: @TheDestroyer when did Barack Obama, Mark Zukurbarg, Donald Trump etc performed Pooja & visited pilgrims? Contrary, average Hindu is more poor (who visit pilgrims) than an average American or European.

Comment: Materially or Spiritually? Narendra Modi did many Pujas who is ruling 130 crore Indians (But i think he follows Karma Yoga). But, seeing everything just wrt to money or fame is bad

Comment: @TheDestroyer Money although not the aim of life but crucial to follow ultimate aim. One who is working 18hour per day for small amount of money can't spend time for spirituality + Karma Yoga is not easy to follow without **losing identification** with the body & mind. NaMo is a very small example.

Comment: Actually, doing our SwaDharma without any expectation is Karma Yoga and it also can grant liberation. God is no where related here, though Bhakti makes it faster or increases probability.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to  ( impossible for common man) do our Swadharma without any expectations.

Comment: Yes. If we don't take help of God, it will be very difficult to get Moksha in this birth.

Comment: Which Hindu scriptures say that Buddha and Mahavira got liberation?

Comment: @Aks Hindu scriptures can't list every enlightened being of future.

Comment: Then what is your basis for saying they "proved the statement wrong".  Anyone can claim to be enlightened, unless Hindu scriptures agree with them, we can't draw any conclusions from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you unnecessarily complicating things up? :D

Its well known that by worshiping Gods we can get both Bhukti (worldly pleasures) and Mukti (liberation).

For example, here is how Lord Shiva describes the greatness of Sri Vidya sadhana in **JyAnarnava Tantram**:

> Vaktra Kotisahasraisthu Jihvakotisatairapi| Varnitum Naiva Shakyem
>   SriVidya Shodashakshari || Vaikhari VAchyabhAvatvAdasagunavarnane | Yato> Niraksharam Vasatu PArA Tatraiva KAranam || MukibhutA Hi Pasyanthi Madyama Madhyama Bhaveth| **BrahmavidyAswarupA Hi BhuktimuktiphalapradA**|| Ekoccharena Deveshi **VAjapeyasya Kotayah|  AswamedhasahsrAni** PrAdakshinam BhuvastathA|| KAshyAditirthayatrAh Syuh SArdhakotitrayanmitAHA|| Tulyam Na YAnthi Devesi NAtra KAryA Vicharana| **Ekoccharena Kim Purnabrahma Kevalam**|| ShodasArna  MahAvidyA Na PrakAshyA KadAchana | GopaniyA TwayA Bhadre Swayoniriva PArvati||
>
> ...................
>
> [Lord Shiva says to Devi Parvati] The greatness of the Shodashi
>   mahavidya can not be described even if one has thousand crores of
>   mouths and hundred cores of tongues. If the mantra is uttered only
>   once one gets the results of performing crores of vAjapeya yajnas and
>   thousands of aswamedha yajnas. **This vidya is brahmavidya and is the
>   giver of both worldly pleasures and liberation**..... Never ever
>   disclose this vidya , it should always be kept secret like your yoni..

Even **Yogini Tantram** says the same about the same vidya or sadhana:

> BhuktimuktipradA VidyA Anthe Kaivalya DAyini ..
>
> ..........
>
> This vidya is the giver of both spiritual and material benefits and in
>   the end is a giver of kaivalya or moksha.

.........................

> Also, As You reap what you sow, there is no possibility that the God
>   will help you to accomplish material things in your life

There is no contradictions here. If you worship God then you are making him happy and if he is happy everyone is happy. So, if you are worshiping God even for your own benefits you are indirectly adding to every being's happiness by doing so. So, this act is an act which results in universal welfare.

For example, see what Lord Sadashiva says to Sri Adya in Mahanirvana Tantram's 4th chapter:

> Twam Sarvaswarupini Devi SarveshAm Janani ParA| **TushtayAm Tvayi
>   Deveshi Sarvesham Toshanam Bhaveth ||** (verse 24).
>
> ............
>
> .......... **When you are happy everyone is happy.**

So, even if you are worshiping God with selfish motives you are indirectly adding to the well being of every creatures in this universe and you are also helping in the proper functioning of the universe. So, you are bound to get both material and spiritual benefits out of it.

> Does worshipping/believing God for sake of liberation is optional
>   though recommended only? Not mandatory?

Liberation is achieved only when we realise the self. This has been mentioned in the Vedas as well as in the Agamas. And, there is no other way.

Now, there are paths ( like Yoga for example) where worshiping Gods is not required in its usual way but still some sort of internal worship and involvement of mantras are there. And Yoga is one of the valid paths to liberation.

So, IMO the answer is-  no its not compulsory. (NOTe : I will support this point with scriptural quotes later, for the time being consider this answer as a partial one.)

Comment: Should we publicize such secrets here?

Comment: I have not given  details of the vidya here.. So don't worry.@Aghori

Comment: People will get through tantra then. -_-

Comment: So finally you're also saying worshipping God for liberation is optional. -_-

Comment: In Yoga do we worship him in the usual way?  But all these methods are interlinked.. all adds up and supplement each other. @Aghori